# css selection is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

am using the following css code for the style, but it is not working with any of the IE version :(

**is there any solution in css or any kind of script(js) can resolve this???**

```
::selection {
background: #990000; 
}

::-moz-selection {
background: #009900; /* firefox*/
}
```

Comment: Is this css 3? if so IE doesn't support it as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html) confirms this isn't supported in IE. I know of no alternative to this (CSS or JS) for IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and later versions already supports `::selection`