# CSS is not loading for my site on IE 7for some unknown reason

Tags: css

CSS is not loading for my site on IE7 for some unknown reason. Its working fine for IE8, chrome and mozilla. You can see the website at [www.fineartsbaroda.com](http://www.fineartsbaroda.com)

Comment: it looks as though the entire page never completely finishes loading in IE7...

Comment: Neither the page nor the CSS pass validation... Potentially a rendering problem because of that...

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with that Facebook like box. Can you remove that and see what happens?

Comment: Hey Skaffman

I just checked your site on IE7 and the CSS seems to be rendering just fine, not sure how to help if I can't replicate.


Leo

Answer (score 1):

Is this answer resolved?

If not, I was going to suggest putting media="screen" for the default.css stylesheet link.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's because of ::-moz-selection.

[css selection is not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149343/css-selection-is-not-working-in-ie)

You may need to add a conditional work-around/hack using something like

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>

<![endif]-->
```